# Want to Generate Auto Login Program Using Java

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I want to develop script or Program which can login and update profile of registered website automatically. Which can did it specific time interval so please guide me and details procedure about it and if u have any study purpose script or program please share with me

I search about it and in PHP there is cURL function is used for such kind of program please Help me Out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of selenium.setup selenium in your eclipse first.
below is the code for login.similarly you can write program for your profile from.

```
public  void login(){

        SeleniumUtils.setTextFieldValue("input#username", "userName");
        SeleniumUtils.setTextFieldValue("input#password", "password");

        SeleniumUtils.clickOnElement("div#btnLogin");

    }

public static void setTextFieldValue(String cssSelector, String value) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebElement field =driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
        field.sendKeys(value);
    }


public  void clickOnElement(String divClass) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(divClass));
        element.click();
    }
```

Comment: sir, but that site third party like facebook,gmail or shine,naukari so how can i fill all details and updated profile on it ?

Comment: can you explain complete scenario.is that you have many users and you want to login and  update there profile?